# Can an NVM device attached via USB adapter be forced to be /dev/nvm* instead of /dev/sd*?

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem, ssd, nvme

I have an M2 NVM storage device that I need to access using nvme-cli, but because the device is connected through a USB adapter, it shows as /dev/sda, so the nvme-cli tool doesn't recognize that as an nvm device.

Is there a way to make the disk show as /dev/nvm*?

Answer (score 1):

Use it as intended a `nvme` drive and you will have access to it as one, as a `USB` device it is always going to be a `/dev/sd?`  device. That is how that protocol works for all them devices by faking its true identity to the system giving it that interface to work with for access.

Comment: Agreed.  The NVM interface is hidden from the computer, abstracted away by the USB interface.  The computer can no longer see the NVM interface, no more than if you put the NVM drive in a file server over a network and tried the utility over Ethernet.